# Find distance between two nodes in an undirected and unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, distance

i want to find the distance from s to t in a graph. how can i change bfs to find distance or use another algorithm that has good `O(n)`. exactly it's important that graph is unweighted and undirected

Comment: How can u measure a distance if the graph is unweighted?

Comment: @Kapa11 Usually 1 is used as a default weight in this case.

Comment: Why do you want to modify bfs? Looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) for reference, it would appear to do what you want more or less out of the box. You root it at s, you iterate until you hit t. Either you keep track of the distance to s while iterating or you count how often you have to call parent to get from t back to s

Comment: @Kapa11 i mean all have same weight like 1.

Comment: As @PaulPanzer says, BFS already does this. Your *implementation* of BFS might not do it, but that's why it's important to include your code when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify **BFS** to find the *(shortest)* distance between two nodes.

Two Important points to note before using this algorithm :

- The **Edges** of the *Graph* have weight either **0** or **1**.
- The Graph is **undirected**  .

Another important thing to note is :

- You do not need a **Boolean** array to mark the node because you need to check the condition for optimal distance when you visit each node.
- A **Deque** is used to store the node.
- if the weight of the edge is **`1`**, then it is pushed to the rear and if it is **`0`**, to the front.

***Implementation***

Here, **edges[ v ] [ i ]** is an adjacency list that exists in the form of pairs i.e. **edges[ v ][ i ].first** will contain the node to which v is connected and **edges[ v ][ i ].second** will contain the distance between v and **edges[ v ][ i ].first.**

Q is a **double-ended queue**. The distance is an array where, **distance[ v ]** will contain the distance from the start node to v node. Initially the distance defined from the source node to each node is **infinity.**

```
void bfs (int start)
{       
        deque <int > Q;     //Double-ended queue
        Q.push_back( start); 
        distance[ start ] = 0;       
        while( !Q.empty ())
            {
            int v = Q.front( );
            Q.pop_front(); 
            for( int i = 0 ; i < edges[v].size(); i++)
            {


            /* if distance of neighbour of v from start node is greater 
            than sum of distance of v from start node and edge weight between v and its neighbour
            (distance between v and its neighbour of v) ,then change it */  


            if(distance[ edges[ v ][ i ].first ] > distance[ v ] + edges[ v ][ i ].second ) 
            {

                distance[ edges[ v ][ i ].first ] = distance[ v ] + edges[ v ][ i ].second;

            /*if edge weight between v and its neighbour is 0 then push it to front of
            double ended queue else push it to back*/

                if(edges[ v ][ i ].second == 0)
                {
                    Q.push_front( edges[ v ][ i ].first);
                }
                else
                {
                        Q.push_back( edges[ v ][ i ].first);

                }
            }
          }
       }
}
```